# Suppose that $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with singular values $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = \sigma > 0$,Let u,v be any pair of orthonormal vectors in $\Re^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with singular values  $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = \sigma > 0$.

a.
Show that if $z\in\Re^2$ with $\Vert z\Vert _2=1$, then  $\Vert Az\Vert _2 = \sigma$.

b.
Let $u$, $v$ be any pair of orthonormal vectors in $\Re^2$. Show that $u$, $v$ are right singular vectors of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that if $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $\|Ux\|_2 = \|x\|_2$.

If $A = U \Sigma V^T$ is a SVD of $A$, then the assumptions give that $\Sigma = \sigma I$, so $A$ can be simplified slightly. Then a. follows by replying the
first comment repeatedly.

For b., note that the singular values of $A$ are the eigenvectors of $A^TA$.
Compute $A^T A$, it has a particularly simple form.